# Como criar um comando para escolher alternativas de linearização

Tags: r

Tenho o seguinte comando para obter coeficientes para linearização da função de Michaelis Menten.

```
# "Estimativas para "CHUTE" 

# 1 para (Eadie-Hofstee  y = -B(y/x) + A)(Especialmente para RMSEA com valores nulos)
# 2 para (x = A(x/y) - B)
# 3 para (Hanes-Woolf  x/y = x/A + B/A)
# 4 para (Lineweaver-Burk  1/y = (B/Ax) + 1/A)

if(ch==1){

  #Alternativa 1   (Eadie-Hofstee  y = -B(y/x) + A)

  dados_Chute <- data.frame(Y=c(Indice),x=c(Indice)/(rep(c(pp), each=100)))   
  options(na.action=na.exclude)
  ajuste<-lm(Y~x,data=dados_Chute)
  A <- (ajuste[["coefficients"]][["(Intercept)"]])
  B <- -(ajuste[["coefficients"]][["x"]])
  C <- A
} else if(ch==2) {

  # Alternativa 2   (x = A(x/y) - B)

  dados_Chute <- data.frame(Y=(rep(c(pp), each=100)),x=(rep(c(pp), each=100))/(c(Indice)))  
  options(na.action=na.exclude)
  ajuste<-lm(Y~x,data=dados_Chute)
  A <- ajuste[["coefficients"]][["x"]]
  B <- -(ajuste[["coefficients"]][["(Intercept)"]])
  C <- 1 - A
} else if(ch==3){

  # Alternativa 3   (Hanes-Woolf  x/y = x/A + B/A)

  dados_Chute <- data.frame(Y = (rep(c(pp), each=100))/c(Indice),x = (rep(c(pp), each=100)))  
  options(na.action=na.exclude)
  ajuste<-lm(Y~x,data=dados_Chute)
  A <- 1/(ajuste[["coefficients"]][["x"]])
  B <- (ajuste[["coefficients"]][["(Intercept)"]])*A
  C <- 1 - A
} else if(ch==4){

  # Alternativa 4   (Lineweaver-Burk  1/y = (B/Ax) + 1/A)

  dados_Chute <- data.frame(Y = 1/c(Indice),x = 1/(rep(c(pp), each=100)))  
  options(na.action=na.exclude)
  ajuste<-lm(Y~x,data=dados_Chute)
  A <- 1/(ajuste[["coefficients"]][["(Intercept)"]])
  B <- (ajuste[["coefficients"]][["x"]])*A
  C <- 1 - A
} else {
  print ("Erro!")
}
```

Preciso criar um comando no qual o usuário do programa possa escolher entre uma das alternativas para estimar os coeficientes (de linearização), a partir da escolha do valor de 'ch', sem que precise repetir todo o comando cada vez que quiser rodar uma das alternativas. Repito isso 4 vezes durante meu programa (uma para cada índice calculado (RMSEA, GFI, NFI e CFI).Estou ajustando uma curva as estimativas calculadas para diversos valores de observações e, as vezes preciso optar por uma das alternativas para linearização (nem sempre é a mesma para todos os índices).

Comment: Você tentou colocar o seu código dentro de uma função que dependa de `ch` ? Pode ser que eu não tenha entendido muito bem o que você deseja.

Comment: Até pensei na sua alternativa, mas pode ter "if" e "if else" dentro de uma função??

Comment: Sim, você pode empacotar `if` `else` dentro de uma função e quando chamar a função você definir qual método quer utilizar.

Answer (score 3):

Uma opção seria criar uma função com a opção `ch`:

```
estimativa <- function(ch)
{
    # testes
    if(!ch %in% c(1:4)) stop("'ch' deve conter um valor entre 1 e 4")

    # "Estimativas para "CHUTE" 

    # 1 para (Eadie-Hofstee  y = -B(y/x) + A)(Especialmente para RMSEA com valores nulos)
    # 2 para (x = A(x/y) - B)
    # 3 para (Hanes-Woolf  x/y = x/A + B/A)
    # 4 para (Lineweaver-Burk  1/y = (B/Ax) + 1/A)

    if(ch==1){

      #Alternativa 1   (Eadie-Hofstee  y = -B(y/x) + A)

      dados_Chute <- data.frame(Y=c(Indice),x=c(Indice)/(rep(c(pp), each=100)))   
      options(na.action=na.exclude)
      ajuste<-lm(Y~x,data=dados_Chute)
      A <- (ajuste[["coefficients"]][["(Intercept)"]])
      B <- -(ajuste[["coefficients"]][["x"]])
      C <- A
    } else if(ch==2) {

      # Alternativa 2   (x = A(x/y) - B)

      dados_Chute <- data.frame(Y=(rep(c(pp), each=100)),x=(rep(c(pp), each=100))/(c(Indice)))  
      options(na.action=na.exclude)
      ajuste<-lm(Y~x,data=dados_Chute)
      A <- ajuste[["coefficients"]][["x"]]
      B <- -(ajuste[["coefficients"]][["(Intercept)"]])
      C <- 1 - A
    } else if(ch==3){

      # Alternativa 3   (Hanes-Woolf  x/y = x/A + B/A)

      dados_Chute <- data.frame(Y = (rep(c(pp), each=100))/c(Indice),x = (rep(c(pp), each=100)))  
      options(na.action=na.exclude)
      ajuste<-lm(Y~x,data=dados_Chute)
      A <- 1/(ajuste[["coefficients"]][["x"]])
      B <- (ajuste[["coefficients"]][["(Intercept)"]])*A
      C <- 1 - A
    } else if(ch==4){

      # Alternativa 4   (Lineweaver-Burk  1/y = (B/Ax) + 1/A)

      dados_Chute <- data.frame(Y = 1/c(Indice),x = 1/(rep(c(pp), each=100)))  
      options(na.action=na.exclude)
      ajuste<-lm(Y~x,data=dados_Chute)
      A <- 1/(ajuste[["coefficients"]][["(Intercept)"]])
      B <- (ajuste[["coefficients"]][["x"]])*A
      C <- 1 - A
    }

    return(c(A, B, C))
}
```